# Google Apps Script - how to access to single values in a CSV file?

Tags: csv, google-apps-script

have a CSV File on Google Drive.
Can access it an see the values. But got only the hole line.

```
function importCSVFromGoogleDrive() {
    
      var file = DriveApp.getFilesByName('file2.csv').next();
      Logger.log(file.getSize());
      Logger.log(file.getName());
      Logger.log(file.getDateCreated());
      var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(file.getBlob().getDataAsString());

      var contdata = csvData[1].toString();

      Logger.log(csvData[1]);
}
```

```
Ausführungsprotokoll
06:20:12
Hinweis
Ausführung begonnen
06:20:13
Info
67.0
06:20:13
Info
file2.csv
06:20:13
Info
Thu Sep 23 15:02:18 GMT+02:00 2021
06:20:13
Info
['Anna', 'Weizenkeim', 'anna@weizenkeim.privat']
06:20:14
Hinweis
Ausführung abgeschlossen
```

How to the for example only the email address / value 3.

---

```
function importCSVFromGoogleDrive() {
    
      var file = DriveApp.getFilesByName('file2.csv').next();
      Logger.log(file.getSize());
      Logger.log(file.getName());
      Logger.log(file.getDateCreated());
      var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(file.getBlob().getDataAsString());

      var contdata = csvData[1].toString();

      var group = ContactsApp.getContactGroup("System Group: My Contacts");
      //bla = contdata.toUpperCase();
      Logger.log(csvData[1].toLocaleString());
      console.log(JSON.stringify(csvData[1],null,' '));
}
```

08:47:28 Info [  "'Anna'",
"'Weizenkeim'",
"'anna@weizenkeim.privat'" ]

Comment: Welcome to [so]. The corresponding content from the CSV file or instead of `Logger.log(csvData[1]);` use `console.log(JSON.stringify(csvData[1],null,' '));` and add the resulting log to the question.

Comment: thanks, but got also all 3 values not one value... see above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just access the third element of the data.

```js
      var contdata = csvData[1].toString();
      var email = csvData[1][2];
      Logger.log(email);
```

Comment: My pleasure. if you think this is a solution, click the checkmark to admit this is the answer. It would be great :) Thanks!